# Akeneo pim 5.0 installation database error

Tags: php, akeneo

I have been trying to install akeneo pim 5.0.
I am getting following error.

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception PDOException: "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'akeneo_pim.pim_session' doesn't exist" at /var/www/akeneo-pim/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/Handler/PdoSessionHandler.php line 625 {"exception":"[object] (PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'akeneo_pim.pim_session' doesn't exist at /var/www/akeneo-pim/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/Handler/PdoSessionHandler.php:625)"} []

Comment: The database doesn't seem to contain the necessary tables.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  i tried to populate database table by using following command
***bin/console pim:installer:db***
74 tables are created. but pim_session table is not created

Comment: See if any of the comments in this [github issue](https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/issues/7196) helps. We have no idea how you've installed the application (and honestly, I have no idea what that application even is so I can't help with more specifics)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks for your comment. Akeneo is product information management  tool. I tried as per official installation documentation.https://docs.akeneo.com/5.0/install_pim/manual/installation_ce.html

Comment: It the guides doesn't work, I would suggest to reach out to their community (they seem to have a slack user group) or post an issue in their github (if things doesn't work as expcted). Did you check the github issue I linked to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is might be an elastic search issue. Before installing your pim copy `.env` to `.env.local` and update the `.env.local` file as per your requirement.